# 2 dfs both have a dates column in same period. 1 has no data on some dates leading to fewer rows. How do I (c)bind these and put NA at missing data?

Tags: r, dataframe, bind

I have these two dataframes that are examples of two different larger dataframes:

```
>df1
     V1            V2     V3
4462 2010-03-20    0      A
4463 2010-03-21    0      A
4464 2010-03-22    0      A
4465 2010-03-23    0,7    A
4466 2010-03-24    8      A
```

and

```
>df2     
     X1           X2            X3
3670 2010-03-20   2.840747e+00   0.0000000
3671 2010-03-21   1.223321e+01   0.0000000
3672 2010-03-22   9.924097e-01   1.3000000
3673 2010-03-24   1.149400e+01   0.0000000
```

As you might have seen already the date: "2010-03-23" in column `df2[,X1]` is missing in contrary to column `df1[,V1]`.

However I still want to bind these date frames into a new date frame (`df3`), e.g. as stated below according to date:

```
     Y1           Y2     Y3  Y4             Y5             
1    2010-03-20   0      A   2.840747e+00   0.0000000
2    2010-03-21   0      A   1.223321e+01   0.0000000
3    2010-03-22   0      A   9.924097e-01   1.3000000
4    2010-03-23   0,7    A   NA             NA
5    2010-03-24   8      A   1.149400e+01   0.0000000
```

I cannot get it to work with `cbind` because of the different number of rows. Does anyone know how to do this? Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
merge(df1,df2,by.x="V1",by.y="X1",all=TRUE)

#           V1  V2 V3         X2  X3
# 1 2010-03-20   0  A  2.8407470 0.0
# 2 2010-03-21   0  A 12.2332100 0.0
# 3 2010-03-22   0  A  0.9924097 1.3
# 4 2010-03-23 0,7  A         NA  NA
# 5 2010-03-24   8  A 11.4940000 0.0
```

Comment: Thx for the respons. However your formula does not result in the neccesary output. It just merges the rows underneath each other instead of next to each other as shown in the example.

Comment: At least is does so when i apply it to the entire dataframes and get this missage: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(10228, 10229, 10230, 10231,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated